# Complicated syntax over Linq and C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I don't know how to understand following syntax:

```
public string[] AuthorReferenceID
{
    get { return this.AuthorReference.Select(auth => auth.@ref).ToArray(); }
}
```

This is a part of the file Bookstore.cs generated by Xsd2 Code Generator from XML Schema. The above code has been added to the generated file. The whole application has been created in order to display content of the XML file.

The XSD document (without first 3 lines) looks as follow:

```
<xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:complexType><xs:complexType name="PersonReference">
        <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="Publication">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AuthorReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="b:PersonReference" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:complexType name="Book">
        <xs:complexContent>
          <xs:extension base="b:Publication">
            <xs:attribute name="price" type="b:positiveDecimal" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="category" type="b:itemCategory" use="required" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>

      <xs:simpleType name="positiveDecimal">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
          <xs:minExclusive value="0" />
          <xs:fractionDigits value="2" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>

      <xs:simpleType name="itemCategory">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="ITC" />
          <xs:enumeration value="Mathemath" />
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>

      <xs:element name="Bookstore">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Books">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Book" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="b:Book" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Journals">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Journal" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Article" type="b:Publication" />
                        <xs:element name="EditorReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="b:PersonReference" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                      <xs:attribute name="price" type="b:positiveDecimal" use="required" />
                      <xs:attribute name="category" type="b:itemCategory" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="People">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element name="Person" type="b:Person" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:key name="PERSON_ID">
          <xs:selector xpath="b:People/b:Person" />
          <xs:field xpath="@id" />
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="ATHBK_PERSON_ID" refer="b:PERSON_ID">
          <xs:selector xpath="b:Books/b:Book/b:AuthorReference" />
          <xs:field xpath="@ref" />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="ATHART_PERSON_ID" refer="b:PERSON_ID">
          <xs:selector xpath="b:Journals/b:Journal/b:Article/b:AuthorReference" />
          <xs:field xpath="@ref" />
        </xs:keyref>
        <xs:keyref name="EDITJRL_PERSON_ID" refer="b:PERSON_ID">
          <xs:selector xpath="b:Journals/b:Journal/b:EditorReference" />
          <xs:field xpath="@ref" />
        </xs:keyref>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the property "AuthorReference" (which I assume is a List or Array of a class), and (if you can) the class of which AuthorReference is a collection of?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't understand"?  Are you having trouble understanding what this should return, or the `=>` notation, or something else?  This is a very simple LINQ call, so it's unclear where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this doesn't exactly explain what's going on, but to break down the Linq:

```
this
```

"this" is a keyword meaning "this object" (or, in other words "this instance of this class). It's not strictly needed, since objects assume they're using their own methods/properties unless otherwise stated.

```
AuthorReference
```

In "this" class there's a property or field called "AuthorReference." How it's used I can assume it's a collection of some sort, likely a List or an array. Without seeing its implementation I can't provide specifics, however.

```
Select(..)
```

"Select" is a Linq method that picks properties or objects from the collection (in this case, "AuthorReference") based on some logic.

```
auth => auth.@ref
```

Most Linq queries follow the format of `variableName => logic`. So you could do, for example, `Students.Where(aStudent => aStudent.Age > 10)`, and get all students that were over 10. "aStudent" or "auth" are both whatever you want them to be.

The code then goes on to appear to reference a property called "@ref" which has some value. So the Select() method is selecting the values of @ref from all AuthorReference items.

```
.ToArray();
```

...Simply turns it from the default value of `IEnumerable<T>` to an array.

In the end the Linq goes through the AuthorReference field/property, and gives you an array of @ref values.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumble across one more problem, when I try to implement get()

```
 public Person[] Author
    {
        get
        { return this.Author.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray(); }
```

I have the comunicat:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'Bookstore.Person[]'.

The important part of the code looks following:

```
public partial class Publication: IPublication
{
    public Person[] Author
    {
        get
        { return this.Author.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray(); }



        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


    public string[] AuthorReferenceID
    {
        get { return this.AuthorReference.Select(auth => auth.@ref).ToArray(); }
    }
}
```

}

where the interface is following:

```
   public interface IPublication
{
    Person[] Author { get; set; }
    string title { get; set; }
    string[] AuthorReferenceID { get; }
}
```

and the rest of the code is presented below:

```
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Book))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2", "1.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com/", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class Publication {

    private PersonReference[] authorReferenceField;

    private string titleField;


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("AuthorReference")]
    public PersonReference[] AuthorReference {
        get {
            return this.authorReferenceField;
        }
        set {
            this.authorReferenceField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string title {
        get {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2", "1.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com/", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class PersonReference {

    private string refField;

    /// <uwagi/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string @ref {
        get {
            return this.refField;
        }
        set {
            this.refField = value;
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2", "1.0.0.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://bookstore.com/", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class Person {

    private string nameField;

    private string surnameField;

    private string idField;


    public string Name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }


    public string Surname {
        get {
            return this.surnameField;
        }
        set {
            this.surnameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <uwagi/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey hegendroffer, I saw this just because I _happened_ to be browsing my previous answers. In the future there's a slim-to-no chance that people will see an expansion to your question if you post it as an answer to a previous question. If you have a new question to a subject with a few days with no activity, go ahead and post it as a new question; you'll get more attention that way.

About this question, though. What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you're just trying to allow the "Author" to be gotten but never (ever, ever) set. This should leave it as a null array, I believe? >>

Comment: >> Also, are you wanting an array of Person objects back or an array of the Author's names? 

If you clarify what you're trying to accomplish/what you want I'd be more than happy to give you a better answer. As-is I'm just not sure how to direct you.

Comment: Thank you for your response !
I want to get an array of Person, so I will be able to print them (by serialization) in the screen. It is my task from university and I am stuck a little bit, but I will appreaciate any help :)

BTW. thank you for your hint :)